# ERROR: Cannot find module './lib/base/events'

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, ghost-blog

I'm getting the error `ERROR: Cannot find module './lib/base/events'` when trying to run Ghost 0.5.0.

I keep uninstalling and installing `events` even with the -g flag, but it doesn't pick it up. I'm stuck here and don't know what else to do.

more info:

```
Error: Cannot find module './lib/base/events'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Bookshelf.initialize (/usr/share/nginx/www/lm-ghost-0.5/node_modules/bookshelf/bookshelf.js:28:16)
    at Bookshelf (/usr/share/nginx/www/lm-ghost-0.5/node_modules/bookshelf/bookshelf.js:10:31)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nginx/www/lm-ghost-0.5/core/server/models/base.js:24:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

SO, I installed the `bookshelf` module manually but now get another error:

```
/usr/share/nginx/www/lm-ghost-0.5/node_modules/downsize/node_modules/xregexp/xregexp-all.js:1396
        L: "0041-005A0061-007A00AA00B500BA00C0-00D600D8-00F600F8-02C102C6-02D1
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Wow, OK, now I installed `xregexp` manually and moving along...

Comment: It is looking for a relative file, not an `events` module. Are you sure the version are trying to use works? What is the stack trace of the error?

Comment: Hey, I updated the question with more info...

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, anybody else comes across this issue, I had to basically watch out for any error and whenever I saw `node_modules/XXX` I simply manually installed module `XXX` and continued to do so for all errors until it worked.